# NatTable - how to implement custom CopyDataToClipboardSerializer

Tags: nattable, nebula

in `CopyDataToClipboardSerializer` I need to override `copiedCells` variable.

I do use `NatTableFactory.class` where I create table, register new `CopyDataCommandHandler`, override table style and so on. But I do not know how to override `CopyDataToClipboardSerializer`. Or should I register new one and create own class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your NatTableFactory class. So I am not sure what you are doing inside that class.

If you need a custom serializer to for example replace line breaks in a text to a space to avoid breaking the table structure, you need to create a custom implementation and use that.

```
class MyCopyDataCommandHandler extends CopyDataCommandHandler {

    public MyCopyDataCommandHandler(SelectionLayer selectionLayer, ILayer columnHeaderLayer, ILayer rowHeaderLayer) {
        super(selectionLayer, columnHeaderLayer, rowHeaderLayer);
    }

    @Override
    protected void internalDoCommand(CopyDataToClipboardCommand command, ILayerCell[][] assembledCopiedDataStructure) {
        ISerializer serializer = new MyCopyDataToClipboardSerializer(assembledCopiedDataStructure, command);
        serializer.serialize();
    }
}

class MyCopyDataToClipboardSerializer extends CopyDataToClipboardSerializer {

    public MyCopyDataToClipboardSerializer(ILayerCell[][] copiedCells, CopyDataToClipboardCommand command) {
        super(copiedCells, command);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getTextForCell(ILayerCell cell) {
        return super.getTextForCell(cell).replace('\n', ' ');
    }
}
```

Then register the custom `MyCopyDataCommandHandler` like this if the headers should be exported too:

```
CopyDataCommandHandler copyHandler =
        new MyCopyDataCommandHandler(
                selectionLayer,
                columnHeaderDataLayer,
                rowHeaderDataLayer);
gridLayer.registerCommandHandler(copyHandler);
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for. Thank you very much, I would buy you a beer or what ever to @Dirk Fauth